# mathematical induction -even number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have solve an exercise but i don't know if i am right.
The exercise says:
Solve with mathematical induction ,to show that the number `n^(2) +5n+4` that it is even.for every n>=0.
**What i did:**
Basic step :k=0
Induction case:k>=0
Induction step:k=n+1
As a result i did this `k^(2) + 5k +4` i replace k=n+1 and i have

```
(n+1)^(2) +5(n+1)+4
n^(2) +2n+1+5n+5+4
n^(2)+7n+10
a=1
b=7
c=10
so D=b^2-4abc = 7*7 -4 *10 =49-40=9
x1,x2=(-b+-√D )/(2*a) = (-7+-3 )/2
so for x1= -7 +3 /2 =4/2=2 
x2=-7-3/2 =-10/2=-5
```

As a result x1=2 it is even.
Does i solve it right?thanks in advance

Comment: For an induction, when you have the base case, the next step is to show that if your statement is true for $n$ it is true also for $n+1$. You should therefore be assuming that $n^2+5n+4$ is even and showing that this implies that $n^2+7n+10$ is even. I am not sure why you are solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: i did it because i wanted to show that  i get from quadratic equation an even number.Is it wrong?

Comment: The roots of the equation are $-2$ and $-5$ and the expression for $n+1$ factors as $(n+2)(n+5)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For n=2

$(2)^2+(5*2)+4$ is even

Our hypothesis $H_n \rightarrow \frac {n^2 +5n+4}{2} = \lambda$

$H_{n+1} \rightarrow \frac{(n+1)^2 +5(n+1)+4}{2} = \frac{n^2 +2n+1+5n+5+4}{2}=\frac {n^2 +5n+4}{2} + \frac {2n+1+5}{2} = \lambda + n+3$

$\therefore \text {for every positive number} H_n $ is true

Comment: lets clear it ,you get the n=2 from my result x1 ? and you go to the equation and you replace it .After you want to test it if that works ,and you find that my solution is right?

Comment: No what you were doing was finding values for particular equation, and luckily you got 2 but in mathematical induction you have prove in general

Comment: So what I showed you how to do mathematical induction

Comment: so i am completely wrong right?

Comment: Yes your method is incorrect

Comment: Try taking the case n+2 you won't be able to prove that it is even but  you  will be able to prove it by my way

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to show that $n^2+7n+10=(n^2+5n+4)+(2n+6)$ and then use that the sum of two even numbers is even. That shows that you can step from the $n$ case to the $n+1$ case.

You can use the base case $n=0$.

You do not need the factorisations $n^2+5n+4=(n+1)(n+4)$ or $n^2+7n+10=(n+2)(n+5)$ though these do confirm that your calculations are correct [2=1+1, 5=4+1].